# How do I get a soprano sound of a ukulele using a capo with a concert ukulele?

Tags: chords, technique, scales, chord-theory, ukulele

Which fret do I put the capo on of a concert ukulele to be equivalent to a soprano?

Answer (score 5):

Concert and soprano ukuleles are (typically) tuned the same, to GCEA.  The difference in sound is tone quality, not pitch.